# Prompt not returning NULL message

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need my table to fill with " ___ not supplied" if the user does not enter anything or does not enter a valid response.

The code works fine if the user presses CANCEL on the prompts, it will fill with "___ not supplied", as I wanted it to. But if the user presses ENTER with no value supplied it will not display the message.

```
<script>

var i = 1;
var jobtitle = [];
var employername = [];
var salary = [];

function Enterjob() {
for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {


    jobtitle.push(prompt("Please enter the job title for advertisement " + i));
    if (jobtitle[i - 1] == null ) {
    jobtitle[i - 1] = "Job title not supplied";
}
    document.getElementById("jobtitle" + i).innerHTML = jobtitle[i - 1];


    employername.push(prompt("Please enter the employer name for advertisement " + i));
    if (employername[i - 1] == null ) {
    employername[i - 1] = "Employer name not supplied";
}
    document.getElementById("employername" + i).innerHTML = employername[i - 1];


    salary.push(prompt("Please enter the annual salary for advertisement " + i));
    if (salary [i - 1] == null || isNaN(salary)) {
    salary[i - 1] = "Annual salary not supplied";
}
    document.getElementById("salary" + i).innerHTML = salary[i - 1];
}
}
</script>
```

I expected any NULL input to display the "__ not supplied" message.

Comment: When you check the value of an empty text input (which i assume you're using), the default value is an empty string (`""`), rather than `null`, just add an extra check on your if statements for  `jobtitle[i - 1] === ""`

Comment: @Snel23 So I changed the if statements to say:
jobtitle.push(prompt("Please enter the job title for advertisement " + i));
 if (jobtitle[i - 1] == "" ) {
    jobtitle[i - 1] = "Job title not supplied";

and it displays the message correctly now if the user hits ENTER with no value, but if the user hits CANCEl it does not display the message

Comment: Just use a `||` to have it run with both the `null` check (for the cancel) and also for the empty string check, rather than getting rid of the null check completely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check the value of an empty text input (which i assume you're using), the default value is an empty string (`""`), rather than `null`.

A simple way to check for this is to add a check for an empty string alongside your `null` check (As the `null` check is looking for the cancel).

Edit: As noted below in the comments, `isNaN()` will always be returning `true` for any string type, so `isNaN(parseInt())` should be used instead

eg.

```
var jobtitle = [];
var employername = [];
var salary = [];

function Enterjob() {
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        jobtitle.push(prompt("Please enter the job title for advertisement " + i));
        if (jobtitle[i - 1] == null || jobtitle[i-1] == "") {
            jobtitle[i - 1] = "Job title not supplied";
        }
        document.getElementById("jobtitle" + i).innerHTML = jobtitle[i - 1];


        employername.push(prompt("Please enter the employer name for advertisement " + i));
        if (employername[i - 1] == null || employername[i-1] == "") {
            employername[i - 1] = "Employer name not supplied";
        }
        document.getElementById("employername" + i).innerHTML = employername[i - 1];


        salary.push(prompt("Please enter the annual salary for advertisement " + i));
        if (salary [i - 1] == null || isNaN(parseInt(salary)) || salary[i-1] == "") {
            salary[i - 1] = "Annual salary not supplied";
        }
        document.getElementById("salary" + i).innerHTML = salary[i - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Snel, I tried this code and it works okay but when entering a real number into the prompts for salary, they return as "__ not supplied"

Comment: i assume that the input is being parsed as a string, which means that `isNaN()` will always return true, try`isNaN(parseInt(salary))`

Comment: I've updated the code snippet to reflect this issue and also to show the full extent of the code

Comment: Yes! this works! Thank you Snel. I'm really not sure why this works. Are you able to explain so I can learn in the future?

Comment: the reason it is working is because when you check the value of an empty text input, the value will be `""`, so we want to make sure that a value was actually entered. As for the `isNaN()`, it returns true or false depending on whether a value "Is Not A Number", and following these rules, a String type (which is what a n `<input type="text">` element will return as a value. Therefore we use `parseInt()` to convert the string to a number before checking it is "Not A Number"

Answer (score 0):

Try using `!variable` to check if the `variable` is set or not:

```
var i = 1;
var jobtitle = [];
var employername = [];
var salary = [];

function Enterjob() {
    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++) {


        jobtitle.push(prompt("Please enter the job title for advertisement " + i));
        if (jobtitle[i - 1] == null || !jobtitle[i - 1]) {
            jobtitle[i - 1] = "Job title not supplied";
        }
        document.getElementById("jobtitle" + i).innerHTML = jobtitle[i - 1];


        employername.push(prompt("Please enter the employer name for advertisement " + i));
        if (employername[i - 1] == null || !employername[i - 1]) {
            employername[i - 1] = "Employer name not supplied";
        }
        document.getElementById("employername" + i).innerHTML = employername[i - 1];


        salary.push(prompt("Please enter the annual salary for advertisement " + i));
        if (salary[i - 1] == null || isNaN(salary) || !salary[i - 1]) {
            salary[i - 1] = "Annual salary not supplied";
        }
        document.getElementById("salary" + i).innerHTML = salary[i - 1];
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work fine apart from the very first salary response in the table.

Comment: bu very first salary response, you mean ? the 1st salary input isn't working ?

Comment: @BreeSergent added a condition to check is salary is supplied or not

Comment: If I load the page and just hit enter or cancel on every prompt, it will display the message in the table everywhere but the first salary cell.

Comment: Tried new code. All cells return the message if nothing is entered but now, if entering an actual number for salary, displays "__ not supplied" message